# extract data (insert command) from the pg dump file

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg-dump

I have a postgres dump file which is exported from Heroku app.

Is there any way to export insert commands from the pg dump file or from Heroku app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dump file is plain text - you can use something like `grep` or other text proceffing tool.

If the dump is binary - use `pg_restore --data-only --file=out.sql dump.file`

Details: [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html)